# Why is the shortest distance between two circles along the segment connecting their centers?

Tags: geometry, circles

I know from visual inspection that to find the shortest distance between two non-intersecting circles as shown in diagram below, one needs to connect their centers and then find the distance between the points where this segment intersects the two circles.

But I could not come up with a geometrical proof for this fact.

**Question**

How would I go about proving the above fact? Any hint would be helpful.

[image: Shortest distance between two points on 2 non-intersecting circles]]

Comment: See whether this helps you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1688605/shortest-distance-between-two-circles

Comment: Thanks. I will have a look at the explanation by Vincent in that post. I was thinking that this is a standard theorem in Geometry, but may be not.

Comment: if a curve is differentiable, and P is the closest point on that curve to the point X, then the line tangent to the curve at the point P will be perpendicular to the line segment XP.

Answer (score 2):

Assume the shortest distance is attained between two other points $C', D'$ on the respective circles, so that $C'D' \lt CD$. Since $AC=AC'$ and $BD=BD'$ that would imply:

$$
AC'+C'D'+D'B \lt AC'+CD+D'B = AC+CD+DB=AB
$$

But the shortest distance between two points is the straight line, so the length of the [broken line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_chain) $AC'D'B$ can be no smaller than that of segment $AB\,$, with equality iff $C'=D$, $D'=D$.

Answer (score 0):

Not phrasing this as a formal proof, but if you draw the tangent lines at $C$ and at $D$ the circles will lie entirely in opposite halfplanes.

Thus, any other segment joining a point on one circle and a point on the other will be longer than the distance between $C$ and $D$ (because tangent lines are perpendicular to radii) which realizes the minimum.

Answer (score 0):

If there are two points $(1,2) $ on two curves symmetric to $y-$ axis as  $ y_1(x), y_2(x) $ satisfying max/min derivative conditions:

$$ x_1=0,y_1^\prime =0 ,\,  y_1^{\prime\prime }  >0 ;x_2=0,\,  y_2^\prime = 0,y_1^{\prime\prime }< 0 , $$

then the minimum distance between points  $1,2$ is $|y_1- y_1|$ occurring along line of symmetry.. the  $y-$ axis.

This holds good for such arbitrary curves and rotations in the $xy$ plane resulting in particular the example you gave.

[image: CircTgts]

At these  *tangent points* direction of normal is same and tangents are parallel.